# using javascript function to render HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a static page that has `login` and `registration` link.I want that when a user clicks on `Login`,it calls a `Javascript` function that in turn displays the `Login Form` on the same page.

Although I can embed the whole HTML tag in `document.write()` but that is very messy and am sure is not the best practice for long HTML codes.

So how can i embed HTML codes into the JS function?and how do i control the positioning of the form on the page.

I am looking for a Javascript solution only and not JQuery

Comment: do you need it to be javascript? why not php?

Comment: Why do you want to program it yourself and not use JQuery?

Comment: Maybe he just wants to learn, personally I like to do the same

Comment: @Sergio : actually i am using PHP as the backend but am not sure if what i want to do can be done using PHP.

Comment: @til_b its a assignment and so hv to use JS only.

Comment: @dragoste i tried with document.write but its very messy.I am currently looking into innerHTML..m new to JS n HTML.

Comment: Maybe just write it in HTML, copy / paste it into `document.getElementById("yourElement").innerHTML = "The HTMl";`, and then correct whatever quote conflicts that occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make a div containing your elements for the registration
So for HTML you can use something like this

```
<div id="regElements" style="display:none;" class="registration" >Elements for a registration form</div>
<input type="button" name="re" onclick="showReg()" />
```

And for Javascript you just use ths function

```
function showReg() {
    document.getElementById("regElements").style.display = "";
}
```

You can find examples of this code everywhere! Good luck!

Comment: This answer solves my question perfectly..Simple !! Thanks @ VladH

Answer (score 5):

```
html = "<form>....</form>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: '#' might not be required for javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use html tag:

```
<iframe id="iframeid" ...>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("iframeid").src="url";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp